# VBA VisibleCell is not Visible

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an issue where a `CellIsInVisibleRange` function selects a cell which it shouldn't.

The code that's looping is as follows:

```
wCount = 0
    loopCount = 0
    For Each wCell In wRange
        loopCount = loopCount + 1
        If CellIsInVisibleRange(wCell) Then
            MsgBox ("HERE IT BE")
            wCount = wCount + 1
            "codey-code"
        End If
    Next
```

The function which fails for me is:

```
Function CellIsInVisibleRange(cell As Range)

     CellIsInVisibleRange = Not Intersect(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, cell) Is Nothing

End Function
```

What's happening is, I've got a visible range of rows being 1, 64, 65, 66.  This loop accepts a **supposedly visible wCell in Row 45.**

I'm looking at this sheet, and that row is most definitely not visible.

Do you see what's wrong with this function?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

@KekuSemau

Thanks for the reply.  That code works well but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to go about doing this.  The line `wCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a "Type mismatch" error but I feel like something like this would be quicker.  I suppose I should have shown that I declare the range I'm seeking over as well.

```
Set wRange = Range("$" & nameColumnLetter & "$1:$" & nameColumnLetter & "$" & lastRow)
    wCount = 0
    loopCount = 0
    For Each wCell In wRange
        loopCount = loopCount + 1
        'If CellIsInVisibleRange(wCell) Then
        If wCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Then
            code
            code
            code
        End If
    Next
```

Am I close to a quicker method here?

Thanks again.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but are you okay with using SpecialCells instead?

Comment: `VisibleRange` seems to return a rectangular range including all rows/columns within the viewport (whether or not they're hidden)

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 ahhh I'd forgotten about that!

Comment: @Tawn Hey, good job trying to implement it. I can help you with your error but need more information. First, here's a line where I use SpecialCells correctly in my own code: `Set Range2 = Range1.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow` So comparing it to your line, you have a type mismatch because SpecialCells is a way to refer to a particular range. but you are trying to see if the cell is a member of that range. Second, are you using loopCount for something before the end? Would it be easier if you just knew the total number of cells in wRange?

Comment: Answer posted below but if you clarify I can make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My work-in-progress answer until we get to discuss a little, here's how I would revise your code:

```
Set wRange = Range("$" & nameColumnLetter & "$1:$" & nameColumnLetter & "$" & lastRow)
    wCount = 0
    'counts blanks and non-blanks, changed from original based on my guess of what you want
    loopCount = wRange.Count 
    Set wRange2 = wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each wCell In wRange2
        code
        code
        code
    Next wCell
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way to go. Intersect wRange2 again with `VisibleRange` before the loop, though.

Comment: @KekuSemau I am missing something, can you help me? I thought @Tawm 's only interest in `VisibleRange` was just as an attempt to find the visible cells in @Tawm 's defined range. Since SpecialCells would already return all of them, why intersect with `VisibleRange`? What did I miss?

Comment: `VisibleRange` is the cells that are currently visible in the window (by window size and scroll position) I'm not sure if that was really intentional, I thought yes...

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveWindow.VisibleRange` does not seem to be very 'intelligent', it bluntly returns the Range form the topleft cell to the bottomright cell.
Try it out: Go to a new sheet, hide Rows 5-10, then hide column E, for example.
Then type this in the immediate window in the VB Editor:

```
?ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address
```

It will output something like `$A$1:$M$47`, ignoring missing ranges.

You can intersect the `VisibleRange` with the non-hidden-cells like this:

```
Public Function CellIsInVisibleRange(cell As Range) As Boolean
    CellIsInVisibleRange = False
    ' wrong sheet active?
    If Not cell.Worksheet Is ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Worksheet Then Exit Function

    ' <Really> visible range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect( _
        ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, _
        ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    CellIsInVisibleRange = Not Intersect(rng, cell) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I responded with an EDIT in my original post.  I'm not sure if @name works here, so I thought I'd get your attention through a comment.  BTW, your way works great!  I'm just looking for a way to maybe not filter through all cells or at least do it faster.

Answer (score 0):

The Range.EntireRow and Range.EntireColumn range objects have a property named "Hidden" that can be checked prior to performing a computationally expensive Intersect evaluation.  In this case, you would check if cell.EntireRow.Hidden is hidden.  If it is hidden, there is no point checking if it is within the visible range.

```
Public Function CellIsInVisibleRange2(cell As Range) As Boolean
    If (cell.Worksheet Is ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Worksheet) Then
        If Not cell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            CellIsInVisibleRange2 = Not (Application.Intersect(cell, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange) Is Nothing)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```